# Isolating water supply to replace basin tap with no local stop valve

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, plumbing-fixture

I got a new tap for a pedestal basin. Looking at the existing fittings there is no local valve to shut off the water at the basin itself where the water pipes come out of the wall & connect to the mixer tap pipes.

All there appears to be is a brass male coupler visually identical this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/22mm-Mlae-Thread-To-G-1-2-Male-Thread-Cooper-Straight-Connectors-Durable-Pure-Brass-Plants/32830027301.html

With no way to shut off the water at the tap itself, what can I do? I can turn off the internal stop cock, but what about the hot water? I've got a combi-boiler system ( 3 story house, the hot water tank & pressure tank are on the 1st floor - no tank in the loft - boiler in the kitchen ) & the house itself is a new build, ~2 years old.

My boss at work suggested that I should be able to turn off the internal stop cock & that *should* mean the pressurised hot water system will eventually stop flowing because it needs the mains water pressure to function? But I'd rather get the advice of people more in the know - I don't want to risk damage to the boiler system. E.g. the boiler in the kitchen explicitly states on the casing 'do not drain'.

Is my boss correct? Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hot will eventually stop by itself, when you've shut off cold. Take the time to put in some proper stop valves on the sink, so that the next time it goes wrong you don't have to cut all water supply.

Comment: Does your house not have a main water shutoff somewhere in the basement or utility spaces?  Any modern build home should. Most valves will fail to shut off entirely if  you never, ever operate them for 20 years, but that shouldn't be a problem in a 2 year old house.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Harper my apologies, to clarify, yes the house has a mains stop cock, which does work - its the pipes at the wash basin that do not have a local valve to stop water at the basin itself.